# Couldn't login with Microsoft Exchange account with azure login

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Microsoft login in my app. But I couldn't log in using Microsoft exchange account, having the OAuth URL as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`

But I get the login prompted with the error :

> isn't in our system.  Make sure you typed your email address
>   correctly. It usually looks like someone@example.com or
>   someone@example.onmicrosoft.com

[image]

Could someone help me fix this?. Do I have to integrate a separate Microsoft Exchange integration or is it a server synchronization issue?

Comment: Is this surely an account in Office 365?

Comment: yes, it is! @juunas. My question is... Can we log in using an exchange account through Office 365?

Comment: It has to be an account in Azure AD, so if this is an on-prem AD account, you need to sync it to an Azure AD with AAD Connect first.

Comment: Oh, I see @juunas! But how do we do it? Is there a possibility of creating a script for it? How do I make my app work with these accounts?

Comment: [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) may be helpful for your scenario.

Comment: That's cool!. Thank you @WayneYang-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to synchronize the account to an Azure Active Directory from on-premises AD first.

You can use [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) to sync accounts. (Replaces the older tool DirSync)

You will have to install AAD Connect on a machine connected to the domain, and go through its guided setup.
You should have the Azure AD ready before you setup the sync.
If you have Office 365, you already have Azure AD :)

Comment: I am  able to get access token for Microsoft work/school by making it multi-tenant. Likewise can't we get access token of that mail ID without syncing them?

Comment: Well... You can only get access tokens for users who are in Azure AD. So some user needs to be there, and that user must have access to the mailbox in Exchange Online.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it is good to go with Azure AD. But how does Exchange online login works?

Comment: Normal Office 365 login, so you will need to have an O365 subscription.

Comment: Could you please let me know if the AAD connect should be done by the user with an on-prem account or should it be done by me for my application in which I am integrating Microsoft login so that it facilitates login for all users with the on-prem account?

Comment: AAD Connect is software which you must install in the domain on-premises. You'll need to have Domain Admin credentials to do that.

Comment: Okay, @juunas. So no other go, the organization of user's with Microsoft exchange has to sync their data to access my Application. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you @juunas. Azure is awesome!